# Reading in values from a file - some are correct, others are incorrect

Tags: c

I need to read in values for three variables from a file, which are then used to perform calculations. 
The values are listed in a specific format. For example, these are the contents of one such file:

```
2  //number of items per variable
0 0 0  //values for center locations (stored as struct)
0 0 .5
10  //values for some variable v1 (type double)
5
-10  //values for some variable v2 (type double)
10
```

This is the code I have for reading in these values:

```
 ...
 fscanf(file, "%d\n", &nItems);
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
 {
  float cx, cy, cz;
  fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &cx, &cy, &cz);

  center[i].cx = cx;
  center[i].cy = cy;
  center[i].cz = cz;
 }
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
 {    
  fscanf(file, "%f\n", &v1[i]);   
 }  
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
 {
  fscanf(file, "%f\n", &v2[i]);   
 }
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I read in the values this way and output them, the values for nItems and the center locations are correct, but the rest are incorrect. However, the signs and relative magnitude of those values are correct. For example, for the list of values shown above, these are the outputted values:

```
Correct              Outputted values
2                    2  
0 0 0                0.000000 0.000000 0.000000  
0 0 .5               0.000000 0.000000 0.500000
10                   524288.000000  
5                    2048.000000
-10                  -524288.000000  
10                   524288.000000
```

I don't know why the values for the last two variables are being read in incorrectly. I would appreciate your advice.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the declaration for v1 and v2? Are they of the correct type for %f?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is it, but from your example file it looked like second two groups of data are integers rather than floating-point values.  In your code, though, you're writing

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
{    
    fscanf(file, "%f\n", &v1[i]);   
}
```

That is, you're reading them using the `%f` specifier, which is for floats.  If the `v1` and `v2` arrays are arrays of `int`s, this won't work correctly; it will overwrite the integers with bit patterns that are meant to be interpreted as floats.

To fix this, try writing this instead:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
{    
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &v1[i]);   
}
```

That is, use the `%d` specifier.

Again, this may be totally off since I can't see more of the code, but if I had to guess this is where I'd put my money.  Let me know if this is incorrect and I can remove this post.

Comment: v1 and v2 are of type double. However, in this example file, the values for those variables happen to be integers. I apologize for not stating that at the start.

Comment: @dpryor- Ah, okay.  To confirm - those arrays are indeed arrays of floats?

Comment: %f is not the correct specifier for double variables. You'd want %lf or change v1 and v2 to type float.